# Unset all environment variables in C-Shell

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I want to unset all environment variables through C-shell script.
With `unsetenv *` command I can do that with command line.
How can we make it work in our script?
I am hitting `undefined identifier issue` when I run through script.

Comment: What is your goal? Unsetting *all* environment variables will likely break things (e.g. think about `HOME`, `USER`, etc.)

Comment: It works for me. Please include the script in your question. On my system, this: `unsetenv * ; /usr/bin/env | wc` prints `      0       0       0` under both csh and tcsh, either on the command line or in a script. (And again, unsetting all environment variables is unlikely to be useful.)

Comment: I don't believe your question can be answered in its current state. Please update it to show a [mcve] (please read the linked article). Are you using csh or tcsh? Along with an exact copy of the script, please include an exact copy-and-paste of the error message (tcsh has no messages containing the word "identifier", and csh probably doesn't either).

Answer (score 2):

From `tcsh(1)`:

```
   unsetenv pattern
           Removes  all  environment  variables whose names match pattern.
           `unsetenv *' thus removes all environment variables; this is  a
           bad idea.  It is not an error for nothing to be unsetenved.
```

So using `unsetenv *` *should* work. It is possible you have a (possible old) (t)csh version that doesn't support this feature?

Either way, as the manual page says unsetting *everything* is probably a bad idea. You will want to keep various variables such as `HOME`, `USER`, and some others. A better way might be something like:

```
foreach e (`env`)
    set name = `echo "$e" | cut -d "=" -f 1`

    # Note: this list should be longer.
    if ( "$name" != "HOME" ) then
        unsetenv "$name"
    endif
end
```

Comment: `unsetenv` is a builtin command, and it doesn't apply normal wildcard rules. `unsetenv *` without quotation marks will unset all environment variables. You *can* quote it in tcsh (in csh quoting it makes it do nothing).

Comment: Hm, it seems you are correct @KeithThompson. I just *assumed* this was the issue without testing it first. Oops! Thanks for pointing that out. The `foreach` loop is still useful I think, so I've changed my answer.

Comment: I haven't checked the history, but I don't think there are any old versions of csh, or especially of tcsh, that don't handle `unsetenv *` correctly. I think the OP has just misstated what the actual problem is. See my latest comment on the question.

Comment: how do you convert the IF statement into a list, can you add another example var to ignore?